# Assign to UIImageView a string tag

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is it possible to assign a text tag to any UIObject? If not is there another way I can do it? Can I do for example:

```
image.tag = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello"];
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The tag property is a NSInteger - therefore no. You may create a subclass and add an NSString property though.

Comment: File -> New -> File then (probably) Objective-C class -> Next -> then pick the object that you want to subclass. Also read this http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_Objective-C_Object_Oriented_Programming

Comment: I shall post my earlier comment as the answer - if you accept then you get rep :) If you have other questions then just post up a new one.

Comment: -1. This shows that 1. you haven't read any documentation, 2. you have no basic idea about Objective-C, yet instead of trying to learn the language before writing an entire OS in it, you ask trivial, googleable questions. You should not do either one.

Comment: @Carbonic: Rather caustic comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the tag is an integer.

Consider subclassing `UIImageView` class and just adding a `NSString` property. It is really simple these days.

Example:

```
@interface TaggedImageView : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tagString;
@end
@implementation TaggedImageView
@end
```

Then just use `TaggedImageView` in place of `UIImageView`.

If you only access the `MyImageView` from one .m file you can just put these lines just after the `#import` statements.

Answer (score 1):

The tag property is an `NSInteger` - therefore this is not possible.

You can create a subclass and add an `NSString` property.